# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Not Booting After Updates

Tags: boot, server, grub2

I am on a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-89-generic x86_64) VPS Server/system, and after I do the updates the server doesnt boot. In my host control panel I can KVM but that just stops at: $grub > After reverting back to the snapshot its okay again.

Any ideas what I can do? I am not a developer so sometimes get stuck with issues.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am going to try updating again to see if I can catch any potential errors right now.

**ADDITIONAL:**
After attempting this again, I get the same issue of not being able to login after updates.

The only warning was this:
Newer kernel available
The currently running kernel version is 5.15.0-89-generic which is not the expected kernel version 5.15.0-91-generic.
Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled automatically, so you should consider rebooting.

And this:
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.

Comment: Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask at the bare minimum I'd like to see the output from `sudo apt upgrade` You might also include the information you wrote in the comment below.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Elder Geek I will take a look at this as I recorder the output and there were no errors. Its on a file somewhere, Il dig it out tomorrow and add it to the bottom of the question. But the only error was with the Linux headers etc as mentioned below. Ill dig it out and post. Thanks.

Comment: Honestly, the current conditions are of more interest than any dated results. Run ‘sudo apt update; apt upgrade’ and post the result. Thank you for helping us help you!